# no sound on acer chromebook 14

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, chromebook

I mostly use arch but I could not get the sound to work on my laptop so I used kubuntu and it worked fine but now when I updated to 20.04 all I get is  `dummy audio` the closest I've gotten to my audio working is downloading this https://pastebin.com/c4qU9hdg then running

`sudo cp <where the file is saved>/asound.state /var/lib/alsa/asound.state`

`sudo alsa force-reload`

`alsactl init`

`sudo alsactl store --file /var/lib/alsa/asound.state`

`sudo alsa force-reload`

it comes up as  `Multichannel Output` and  `Multichannel input` and they don't work

Comment: Install Pulse Audio Volume Control.  Poke around in the settings and see if you find something muted or not the correct defaults.

Comment: what is the name of the package?

Comment: the name is pavucontrol

Comment: fixed it I changed the configuration to stereo output it says unavailable but it works going to try on arch

Comment: can't get headphones to work :/ I'm 9999999999999999% sure this is due to a update maybe it's reverted I might have better luck with arch I could also try somehow downgrading audio packages it's not like I need the newest pulse audio it's already bloat